# Independence of two variables given a finite covariance with a third variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that we have three continuous variables A, B, and C, whose joint probability distribution is P(A,B,C) = P.

We are given that the two covariances

$\langle AB \rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle$ and $\langle AC \rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle C \rangle$ are both positive (bounded from below by some q>0).

In the above, $\langle X \rangle$ denotes the average of X with the probability distribution P.

What bounds (if any) does the positivity of the latter two covariances imply on the third covariance $\langle BC \rangle - \langle B \rangle \langle C \rangle$?

*** In a related vein, can B and C be independent? ***

---

I must apologize if I overlooked earlier questions (and answers) on this website. There were questions concerning correlations yet these seemed to concern other issues. Nonetheless, I may have easily missed previous pertinent questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\langle X Y \rangle - \langle X \rangle \langle Y \rangle = \text{Cov}(X,Y)$, the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, $\sigma(X) = \sqrt{\text{Cov}(X,X)}$ the standard deviation of $X$, and $\rho(X,Y) = \text{Cov}(X,Y)/(\sigma(X) \sigma(Y))$ the Pearson correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$. 
Then it can be shown that
$$ \rho(B,C) \ge \rho(A,B) \rho(A,C) - \sqrt{1 - \rho(A,B)^2} \sqrt{1 - \rho(A,C)^2}$$

In particular, if $\rho(A,B) > t>0$ and $\rho(A,C) > t>0$, then $\rho(B,C) > 2 t^2 - 1$.
In order for this to guarantee that $B$ and $C$ are positively correlated (and thus not independent), you'd need $t > 1/\sqrt{2}$.

EDIT: You can obtain the inequality as follows.  For convenience, normalize the random variables $A, B, C$ so that their means are $0$ and standard deviations are $1$ (note that transformations $X \to a X + b$ for $a > 0$ do not change correlation coefficients).  Let $B_1 = B - \rho(A,B) A$.  Then $\langle B_1 A \rangle = 0$ and $\langle B_1 \rangle = 0$ so $\sigma(B_1)^2 = \langle B_1^2 \rangle = 1 - \rho(A,B)^2$.  Similarly if
$C_1 = C - \rho(A,C) C$, $\sigma(C_1)^2 = 1 - \rho(A,C)^2$.  And now using Cauchy-Schwarz, 
$$ \eqalign{
\rho(B,C) &= \langle (B_1 + \rho(A,B) A)( C_1 + \rho(A,C) A) \rangle\cr
&= \langle B_1 C_1 \rangle + \rho(A,B) \rho(A,C) \cr
&\ge \rho(A,B) \rho(A,C) - \sigma(B_1) \sigma(C_1) \cr
&=  \rho(A,B) \rho(A,C) - \sqrt{1 - \rho(A,B)^2} \sqrt{1 - \rho(A,C)^2}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this. A brief question: where does the above inequality follow from?